# How to fix/set proportions of OpenGL window in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, opengl, 3d

I am running a graphical application in virtual box, it has an OpenGL viewport. The problem is that the display is 'squashed', the proportions are wrong. It's something like:

- something doesn't believe the pixels are square
- something is scaling the x and y dimensions differently

The symptom is that circles are drawn as ellipses, squares are rectangles wider than they are tall, diagonal squares are diamond shapes stretched wide in the horizontal direction.

Circles in say 'mspaint' look circular, so I'm leaning to toward the issue being either the software or the display driver for 3D.

Any ideas or requests for further useful information?

Comment: Have you installed Guest Additions in the VM? See also this [bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12048).

Comment: @harrymc Yes I have the guest additions installed. Can't see anything about resolution, proportion etc. in that bug report.

Comment: Check the unconfirmed registry patch at the end of the bug report.